# Creating multiple fixtures in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I've been trying, but in vain, to create multiple fixtures in cakePhP.  Currently, I need to test a function that requires two different fixture database tables.  If possible, could someone please post some simple snippet and show me create multiple fixtures.

Answer (score 4):

Furnace,

have you taken a look at cake's `bake` utility? You can bake fixtures with it.

```
cake bake fixture all
```

bakes all fixtures at once in your app. Use with care in order not to overwrite existing code.

**Edit0:**
Use

```
cake bake fixture help
```

if you have further questions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple fixture: **app/tests/fixtures/entity_fixtures.php**
In your case you will create two of these files, one per model and with different names.

```
<?php  
 class EntityFixture extends CakeTestFixture { 

    var $name = 'Entity'; 
    var $table = 'entities';

    // Define the fields
    var $fields = array(
        'entity_id'     => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'type'          => array('type' => 'string' , 'length' => 255),
        'created'       => 'datetime',
        'modified'      => 'datetime'

    );

    var $records = array( 
        array('entity_id' => 1, 'type' => 'entity', 'created'=>'2010-01-01', 'modified' => '2010-01-01')

    ); 
 } 
 ?>
```

When in your test case include your fixtures at the top of your test case

```
class EntityTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

    var $fixtures = array(
        'plugin.myplugin.entity',     // Including a sample plugin fixture
        'entity',                     // The fixture above shown in code above
        'blogs'                       // Including a third fixture (should be in app/tests/fixtures/blog_fixture.php)
    );
}
```