# drop and create tables with fixtures on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, testing

I have already seen this question:

[CakePHP PHPUnit Fixtures Drop Database Table Every Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198435/cakephp-phpunit-fixtures-drop-database-table-every-time)

[Creating multiple fixtures in cakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198375/creating-multiple-fixtures-in-cakephp)

[CakePHP Test Fixtures Drop My Tables Permanently After Running A Test Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535866/cakephp-test-fixtures-drop-my-tables-permanently-after-running-a-test-case)

But this links are old I think.

I would like to create test where Im'loading fixtures so test drop tables and create it with records.

My problem is that: Tests drop taboles btu it doesn't recreate it.

This is my model where I'm loading fixtures:

```
App::uses('Post', 'Model');

class PostTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array('app.post');

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Post         = ClassRegistry::init('Post');
    }

    public function testSetTemplate() {

        $this->assertEquals('1', '1');
    }
}
```

And this is my fixture file:

```
class PostFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public  $import = array('model' => 'Post', 'records' => true);

    public $name = 'Post'; 
    public  $table = 'posts';

    public $fields = array(
        'id'                => array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 36, 'key' => 'primary'),
        'created'        => array('type' => 'datetime'),
        'modifed'        => array('type' => 'datetime')
    );

    public $records = array(
        array(
            'id'                => '1',
            'created'           => '2014-01-17 12:31:41',
            'modified'          => '2014-07-22 09:50:42'
        ),
    );
}
```

I have also tried with:

```
public  $import = array('model' => 'Post', 'records' => false);
```

Same thing tests drop tables but doesn't create it.

I need to create it after drop with my records.

Where s the error? Why tests doesn't recreate it table posts but only drop it?

Thanks

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/2535897/1392379** ? maybe...

Comment: is one of the link that I have read already but not helped me :( @ndm

Comment: And it didn't help because you are properly using either a separate database for the test connection, or a unique prefix?

Comment: I'm using a separate database for tests sure